# How can I share a value from one page to another in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this page:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Japanese
{
    public partial class PhrasesPage : ContentPage
    {

        public PhrasesPage()
        {
            var x = 99;
        }
    }
}
```

and this page:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Japanese
{
    public partial class PhrasesPage2 : ContentPage
    {

        public PhrasesPage2()
        {
            var y = x;
        }
    }
}
```

It's a very much simplified example but what I would like to know is how can I share the value of x so that it can be used on the PhrasesPage2>

Comment: I'm sorry, but this seems very basic programming knowledge. Did you search for any answers yourself yet? What have you tried?

Comment: If this were standard C# then no problem but I am learning about Xamarin Forms and my question is specific to forms.  Would appreciate you telling me how many variables can be shared between forms.

Comment: There are many choices: you can use static variables, you can pass values via constructor, you can use App variables like Application.Current.Properties, you can use Messenger to set values

Answer (score 1):

You will pass the value using the constructor of PhrasesPage2:

```
public PhrasesPage2(int x)
    {
        var y = x;
    }
```

Than on page 1 when you want to navigate to page 2, you just pass the value when move to that page(here you use yourmethod you mostly use to navigate):
Navigation.PopAsync(new PhrasesPage2(x));